# How do I find find the index of the greatest integer in a list that contains integers and strings in Python?

Tags: python

Thats how the list looks like

`incomes = ['Kozlowski', 52000, 'Kasprzak', 51000, 'Kowalski', 26000]`

I want to print the biggest income and the surname of the person with that income (index of the income - 1)

Comment: You should create dictionary

Comment: Indent your code properly and let understand others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pattern is `["SURNAME_1", INCOME_1, "SURNAME_2", INCOME_2, ... ]`, then you can do this:

```
prices = incomes[1::2] # This will return all integers
names  = incomes[::2]  # This will return all surnames

max_price = max(prices)
max_price_index = prices.index(max_price)
person = names[max_price_index]
```

but you should really change it to dictionary, as it is easier to work with, and it's more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
index_of_highest_salary = incomes.index(np.max(incomes[1::2]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `dict` from your data, then use `max` to find the key with the largest corresponding value.

```
>>> incomes = ['Kozlowski', 52000, 'Kasprzak', 51000, 'Kowalski', 26000]
>>> data = dict(zip(incomes[::2], incomes[1::2]))
>>> data
{'Kozlowski': 52000, 'Kasprzak': 51000, 'Kowalski': 26000}
>>> max(data.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
('Kozlowski', 52000)
```

Then you don't need indexing and the data is more structured.

Comment: Thank you so much I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your title question is different to what you're asking, so here's an answer for your title:
If you don't want to use other libraries like numpy, you can do this:

```
index = 0
max_n = None
for i in range(len(incomes)):
   element = incomes[i]
   if type(element) == int or type(element) == float:
     if max_n is None or element > max_n:
       max_n = element
       index = i
```

`index`  will hold the index of the largest number of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you want the index of the entry as stated in the title of your question.

Use `enumerate` to create data where index and value are combined.

```
incomes = ['Kozlowski', 52000, 'Kasprzak', 51000, 'Kowalski', 26000]
print(list(enumerate(incomes[1::2])))
```

This will give you `[(0, 52000), (1, 51000), (2, 126000)]`.

We can now feed this data to `max` and use a key function that gives us the second entry of each tuple. When we get this tuple we can get the index from the first entry in the tuple. Since we left out every second element (the name) this index must be multiplied by `2`.

```
incomes = ['Kozlowski', 52000, 'Kasprzak', 51000, 'Kowalski', 26000]
max_income = max(enumerate(incomes[1::2]), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(max_income[0] * 2)
```

---

If you want the index and the entries the code can be adjusted.

```
max_income = max(enumerate(zip(incomes[::2], incomes[1::2])), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
print(max_income)
```

This will give you a tuple with an index as the first entry and a tuple with name and income as the second entry. To map this index to your `incomes` list it will have to be multiplied by `2`.